# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size

Tags: python

How do i fix this unexpected keyword argument 'size'?

---

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "H:\Documents\Astro game\astro games6.py", line 73, in <module>
        main()
      File "H:\Documents\Astro game\astro games6.py", line 61, in main
        new_asteroid = Asteroid(x = x, y = y,size = size)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'
```

---

The full code:

```
import random
from superwires import games

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

class Asteroid(games.Sprite):
    """ An asteroid wich floats across the screen"""
    SMALL = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    LARGE = 3
    images = {SMALL : games.load_image("asteroid_small.bmp"),
              MEDIUM : games.load_image("asteroid_med.bmp"),
              LARGE : games.load_image("asteroid_big.bmp")}
    speed = 2

    def _init_(self, x, y, size):
        """Initialize asteroid sprite"""
        super(Asteroid, self)._init_(
            image = Asteroid.images[size],
            x = x, y = y,
            dx = random.choice([1, -1]) *Asteroid.SPEED* random.random()/size,
            dy = random.choice([1, -1]) *Asteroid.SPEED* random.random()/size)

        self.size = size


    def update (self):
        """ Warp around screen"""
        if self.top>games.screen.height:
            self.bottom = 0

        if self.bottom < 0:
            self.top=games.screen.height

        if self.left > games.screen.width:
            self.right = 0

        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = games.screen.width

class Ship(games.Sprite):
    """The player's ship"""
    image = games.load_image("ship.bmp")
    ROTATION_STEP = 3

    def update(self):
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_LEFT):
            self.angle -= Ship.ROTATION_STEP
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_RIGHT):
            self.angle += Ship.ROTATION_STEP


def main():
    nebula_image = games.load_image("nebula.jpg")
    games.screen.background = nebula_image

    for i in range(8):
        x = random.randrange(games.screen.width)
        y = random.randrange(games.screen.height)
        size = random.choice([Asteroid.SMALL, Asteroid.MEDIUM, Asteroid.LARGE])
        new_asteroid = Asteroid(x = x, y = y,size = size)
        games.screen.add(new_asteroid)


    the_ship = Ship(image = Ship.image,
                    x = games.screen.width/2,
                    y = games.screen.height/2)

    games.screen.add(the_ship)

    games.screen.mainloop()

main()
```

---

I have tried removing the size argument but it caused more errors in the code. We also tried changing the size tag to something else to see if that helps and it didn't work either. So I'm stuff for what I need to do to make this code work. I am working on it for a class project in school. English is not my first language so I have had a classmate write this up.

Thank you.

Comment: remove size from the list of arguments...

Comment: Could you please show some code? What object are you trying to initialize? If you wrote this object, does `__init__` have parameter `size`? If this is external code, is parameter `size` documented?

Comment: Can you please share Asteroid class __init__() function code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Asteroid class defines `_init_` instead of `__init__`. You need two underscores on either side for Python magic methods.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the `size` argument in your code.

*note: a Python module name shouldn't have a space: you won't be able to import it in another module.*

Comment: But what if he needs the `size` argument? He shouldn't just delete it. He should learn how to fix the problem.